# Regex captuing group

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to capture host address from string with regex. My code looks like the following:

```
private static final Pattern OBTAIN_HOST_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("Host:\\s?(.*)");
public static String getHostAddress(String line) {
    Matcher m = OBTAIN_HOST_PATTERN.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return OBTAIN_HOST_PATTERN.matcher(line).group(1);
    }
    return "Pattern does not match.";
}
```

Then I call `getHostAddress("Host: abc");` and it gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` which means it matches the pattern but group capturing does not work. So, could you please help me find out why does this happen and what I am missing. Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I resolved the issue. It was because I am getting the matcher twice (or at least I think this was the reason), but can someone explain why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
return OBTAIN_HOST_PATTERN.matcher(line).group(1);
```

calls neither `matches` or `find`. As the `if` statement has already found a match so you can just do

```
return m.group(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even do better, by naming your group so you don't get confused with group indexes while trying to find your corresponding group. It can be achieved by doing the following thing :

`"Host:\\s?(?<mygroupname>.*)"`

and then

`m.group("mygroupname")`

A bit of doc about it : https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/named_capturing_group_in_jdk7